# show that integral converges even if it has a singularity

Tags: analysis, integration

i am currently reading through a book on generalized functions, and there it is said that:

> ... $\int_{|x|\le r} |x|^{-t} dx$ converges for $t < n$ (in $n$ dimensions) and 
>   diverges for $t \ge n$.

Why does it converge for $t < n$, its area/volume still goes to infinity near zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spherical coördinates.  The $c_n$ shown below is the surface area measure of $S^{n-1}$.

$$\int_{B_r(0)} |x|^{-t}\, dx = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_0^r \rho^{-t} \rho^{n-1}\,d\rho\,d\sigma  = c_n \int_0^r \rho^{n-1-t}d\rho$$

The last integral converges  iff $n-1-t > -1$, or if $n > t$.